# Xcode Objective-c warnings "creating selector for nonexistent method" with OCUnit (SenTestingKit)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-warnings, ocunit

I started getting getting warnings like the following in XCode when trying to write some unit tests with OCUnit (SenTestingKit).

```
warning: creating selector for nonexistent method 'myMethodName1:'
warning: creating selector for nonexistent method 'myMethodName2:'
...
warning: creating selector for nonexistent method 'release'
warning: creating selector for nonexistent method 'retain'
warning: creating selector for nonexistent method 'alloc'
warning: creating selector for nonexistent method 'init'
```

Is it something I should worry about, or can I somehow disable these types of warnings by some compiler flag?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20664918/751932

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see if this helps you with your problem:
http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg09557.html